# Why do we have only GitHub and Twitter in developer story?

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

In *developer story* there is the possibility of adding social links, but they are limited to only GitHub and Twitter.

[image: developer_story]

If there is Twitter, why don't we have other socials? Someone pointed out that Linkedin and Facebook can be seen as direct rivals of SO developer story but there are a lot of other socials.

One could say that socials are not so important in a resume. But git projects could be very important to show to a potential employer. We have GitHub but where are GitLab and Bitbucket?

Are there some agreements between them and Stack Exchange?

One could argue that there is also the possibility to add only one website while one user could have more, but at least is his choice which one is the most important one. Even if I think that my GitLab account is more important than GitHub one I cannot insert it.

Comment: Related, and also unanswered: [Add social media link and professional link to CV](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338512), [Add link to LinkedIn profile in new Developer Story profile](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320911)

Comment: And they older than 1 year. So I think there is no possibility to have my question answered.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a lot of demand for it. That first link is a proper `feature-request` and only has 3 upvotes (and one down). You could theoretically add a Milestone and put a bunch of links in it, but that seems hacky at best.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, Well, it reached 17 votes (I don't know how much up or down) without putting anything useless. I hope that soon or later someone from SE would see it.

Comment: Well, we probably need to cater for the mysterious spike in GitLab and BitBucket account creation!

Comment: @halfer, it's not so mysterious. ;)

Comment: Well, yeah, tens of thousands of people think the UI amendments to the merge workflow are a regressive step. They're welcome to their opinion, of course.

Comment: @halfer, emh... honestly I was thinking to the acquisition of GitHub by Microsoft.

Comment: `<giggle>` Oh, I had no idea `</giggle>`

Comment: @halfer, From [this graphs](https://monitor.gitlab.net/dashboard/db/github-importer?orgId=1&from=now-30d&to=now) I think that there be some correlation. :)

Comment: I can understand not having a LinkedIn link, since LinkedIn is a competitor to Developer Stories in many ways, but I would think Facebook would be as relevant (or not) as Twitter.

Comment: @user1118321 [Facebook could also be considered competition](https://www.facebook.com/business/news/take-the-work-out-of-hiring)

Comment: The real question is why can't it simply be a series of links we think are relevant? Besides the great chance for hilarity, it then wouldn't be hard to associate by domain.

Comment: Ok, I understand Linkedin (and maybe also Facebook). But even if we don't consider competitors there are still a lot than ones could want to include.

Comment: might as well ask if M$ has any plans for SO

Comment: I really don't see why Twitter and Facebook are relevant. You want to send cute kid/cat pictures and internet memes to your future employer?

Comment: @prusswan I don't think it's going to happen.

Comment: @Lundin, Twitter is already there. And if twitter is good for SE administrators I don't know why other socials aren't. Ok, possible competitors like Linkedin and Facebook have a reason to not be in there. But I really don't understand why one cannot link Bitbucket or GitLab that are basically the same of GitHub.

Comment: Why not just "Social media handle" and "Code respository" if we just want one?

Comment: @gvgramazio LinkedIn I could understand, but not Twitter or Facebook. What message are you trying to send your employer? "I spend most of my time at work on social media"?

Comment: @Pureferret, I would prefer to have the opportunity to insert all the repository and all the social media. But if I have to choose between Twitter&GitHub vs one-social&one-git-repository obviously I will choose the latter.

Comment: @Lundin I see nothing wrong with having Twitter. It can be used for promoting open source projects, interacting with dev community, sharing blog posts etc.

Comment: @Lundin. Sorry, perhaps I didn't explain myself good enough. Twitter isn't a request of mine, Twitter is already there. I only said that if we have Twitter we should have also other social media. Is up to you if you want to show your social media or not to your employer and which message you want to send. Other noted that Linkedin and Facebook could be seen as direct competitors of SO developer story so that could be a reason to not insert them. I agree, and if there are reasons I don't complain.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what "Developer Story" is about. If it is yet another "here's some cool stuff on the internet" site, well then it can obviously contain anything, including cat pictures.

Comment: @Lundin, But other than Twitter there are also other social media that aren't direct competitors. So I think that we should have the possibility to insert them all or none of them.

Comment: @Lundin, If one to complain about developer story in general this is another story and a lot of debate has been done on meta. But I don't think this is the point now. Also, I didn't say that it could contain anything. I said that if there is the possibility to insert one social than it should be the possibility to add all the social (that doesn't are directly competitors). But most important, and this is why I don't want to focus on socials too much, if one can link his/her list of repos on GitHub, he/she should be able to link also the repos on other websites.

Comment: @Lundin There's nothing stopping you putting cat pictures on your CV (or resume if you prefer), it's a choice you make. I regularly see CVs with Twitter profiles attached. Rarely are they useful of course, but it has happened.

Comment: Answer : Remove all social media links

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson Yeah, I could also say to remove the developer story at this point. No developer story, no troubles that comes from it.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson Remove *all* the *things*!

Comment: @AgiHammerthief It is also good idea. They we have no problem.

Comment: Certainly, they do not want to play with the kids!

Comment: @AkbarTaghipour I don't get the point of your comment.

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same thought as to why there were only a couple of slots for links and two of those have particular designations.

I'd like to have some number of slots that would allow whatever URI I wanted to specify.

One thing I don't know is what the underlying server functionality needs to know about a particular slot's contents so that the server can handle it properly. Websites with a standard URI, such as https://stuff.com/joeybarnes/, would have the type as part of the URI however I have no idea as to what is required to support a Twitter URI.

For myself, I don't use Twitter and Facebook is personal. I do have a LinkedIn profile, a GitHub account, and a *[Code Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Project)* account along with my Stack Overflow account. And I've just started with a [Reddit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit) account.

I am curious as to what others use fairly regularly and would love to see some comments or other posts to this question especially for something.